# import CSV to pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I tried to import a csv to my db, on public schema with pgAdmin 3

```
create table public.output (
x char (50),
y char (50),
id integer ,
nombre char (50),
departamento char (50),
provincia char (50), 
pais char (50))
```

but, when I use COPY

> copy public.output from 'C:\output.csv' delimiter ',' csv header 
>   ---- ERROR: no se pudo abrir archivo «C:\output.csv» para lectura: No such file or directory ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: no se pudo abrir archivo «C:\output.csv» para lectura: No such
>   file or directory Estado SQL:58P01

Comment: `COPY` is server side statement and requires file to reside on server

Answer (score 2):

You can import it directly from pgAdmin.

In the schema >> Public >> Tables >> the table that you want to import the CSV in.

Then right-click >> import >> define your file location, Encoding (normally UTF8), Delimiter (normally ;) and active the header.

Comment: Thx, i use access to import csv to postgresql.. and create a function.